# Fastest way to set pixel in java

Tags: java, performance, graphics

Am making a "Falling Sand" based game, were performance of placing Materials (Pixels with RGB values) is very important, currently how i place pixels is, i have a buffered image and i do  `img.setRGB(x,y,SandColor)`, which probably is not the fastest, because of several reasons most importantly i have to clear that buffered image which makes fps drop from 600 to 144, I do clearing by calling this method:

```
private void clear(){
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
g.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
g.dispose();
}
```

How can i improve screen clearing and performance in general.

Comment: Have you tried just making a new image? (assuming there's nothing in the old one you want to keep)

Comment: Yes and performance went from 140-146fps to 72-128fps, so not great

Comment: The Java GUI really isn't designed for this sort of performance.  It's designed for windows and buttons, not high performance gaming.  You can do some work this it: https://pavelfatin.com/low-latency-painting-in-awt-and-swing/ But mostly if I was making a game in Java I'd get jogl or lwjgl and use that.

Comment: I tried lwjgl, but because of my bad experience i made performance much worse

Comment: Another possibility is to use `BufferedImage.setData()`. I don't know if it's faster, but worth a try.